Api platform V3 embedded resource dataprovider
I have a User entity and a File entity (with Symfony, ApiPlatform V3).
In the User entity I have a fileAvatar relationship which is of type File.
Each time I read a File (for all my resources: user.fileAvatar, enterprise.fileLogo...), I would like to add an url (computed with the UrlGeneratorInterface service): which allows to view the binary.
I achieved this with a Normalizer.
But I don't know if this is correct way because File is no longer a subresource.
I would like do it with a "SubresourceDataProviderInterface".
Does anyone know how to make a provider to apply to a subresource regardless of the context?
Thank you in advance.
